# Download file from GCP bucket without using decompressive transcoding by default

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-client

## TLDR

**Goal**: Download file without decompressive transcoding from a bucket in GCP.
**Scenario**

1. Metadata is set as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding) (cache-control set to `no-transform`, content-encoding to `gzip`, content type to `application/json`

**What I did**

1. Doing the curl command only with no-transform in cache control (metadata of the stored file) doesn't work
2. Doing the curl command with header Accept-Encoding works

**Conclusion:** Need to send Accept-Encoding header

**Problem:** The Node.js client for GCP in their `File.download` method doesn't seem to have a way to change the headers of the request.

---

### Old Question

I have stored a gzip file in a bucket. The metadata of this file is:

- Content-type: application/json
- Content-encoding: gzip
- Cache-control: no-transform

As per their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding):

> When an object meets these two criteria, it undergoes decompressive transcoding when served, and the response containing the object does not contain a `Content-Encoding` or `Content-Length` header.
>
> There are two ways to prevent decompressive transcoding from occurring for an object that is otherwise eligible:
>
> - If the request for the object includes an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header, the object is served as-is in that specific request, along with a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header.
> - If the [`Cache-Control`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2) metadata field for the object is set to `no-transform`, the object is served as a compressed object in all subsequent requests, regardless of any `Accept-Encoding` request headers.

The `no-transform` should prevent that when downloading the decompressive transcoding take place. It does, so I tried solution one that is sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip` which works great with my `curl` command.

However, I'm using the Node.js client library `File.download` method which apparently seems to ignore everything and worst of all I can't find how to adapt the headers of this call.

#### Code

```js
import { Storage, File, Bucket, CopyOptions, GetAclResponse } from '@google-cloud/storage'


export const downloadFile = async (file: File, destination: string)=>{
    try {
       await file.download({destination})
    } catch {
    // something
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to do it using the client library?

Thank you, very much

- Tried adding `no-transform`
- Looked for the documentation, no success

Comment: When referencing documentation, include a link to the documentation. When referencing code, include a complete example of the code. The goal is that you provide enough detail to reproduce the problem and we can provide an answer without guessing or assuming.

Comment: Well, I added the info you required :)

1) Metadata is set as per documentation
2) Doing the curl command only with no-transform in cache control (metadata of the stored file) doesn't work
3) Doing the curl command with header Accept-Encoding works
4) Node.JS File.download method don't accept modification of headers